# Generate element live and put his content in a new live generated element

Tags: jquery, dom

I have two forms both have auto increments rows. When I click on the add button so far the code is working fine as per my need. But now I want to post the value from one row to the other which is incremented in other table. At the same time I have the javascript code but that code does not seems to work properly in the autoincrement function.
 Here is my jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var currentItem = 7;
            $('#addnew').click(function() {
                currentItem++;
                $('#items').val(currentItem);
                $('#items2').val(currentItem);
                var strToAdd = '<tr><td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="ord_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="ord_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup=$("#ordby_'+ currentItem +'").val($("#ordby_'+ currentItem +'").val())/></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="srno' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="srno_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById("srno_' + currentItem + '").value = this.value;"/></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_' + currentItem + '" id="descrip_' + currentItem + '" cols="70" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById("descrip_' + currentItem + '").value = this.value;"></textarea></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="unit_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById("unit_' + currentItem + '").value = this.value;"/></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="rate_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="rate_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById("rate_' + currentItem + '").value = this.value;"/></td></tr>';

                var strToAdd3 = '<tr><td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="ord_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="ord_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth"  /></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="srno_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="srno_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth"  /></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><textarea name="text_' + currentItem + '" id="descrip_' + currentItem + '" cols="70" style="display: none;"></textarea></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="unit_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"  /></td>\n\
                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="rate_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="rate_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"  /></td></tr>';

                $('#data').append(strToAdd);
                $('#data3').append(strToAdd3);

            });
        });

    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: you should use `on` for dynamically loaded content, please refer to this link http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: on??? sir m  a newbie so can  u please elaborate?

Comment: By the way, if I read correctly, you're having same `id`'s in two different input elements. Ids should be unique, and only appear once.

Comment: sir actually the other table will held invisible and the user will jus insert the values in the first tables textbox and the inputs should get copied inanother table while he inputs it

Comment: so you want to copy values of input elements from #data to #data3? If so, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remove this...

`onkeyup=$("#ordby_'+ currentItem +'").val($("#ordby_'+ currentItem +'").val())`

...and add this event

```
$( '.class-name-for-input-element-you-want-to-attach-event-to' ).on( 'keyup', function() {
    var itemIdx = parseInt( this.id.substr( 4 ), 10 ); // Strips the 'Ord_' from the id
    // Do whatever you need to do with the integer

    // Find element in #data3 and replace its value with the value in the element that triggered this event
    $( '#data3' ).find( 'selector' ).val( this.value );
});
```

In order this to work, you'll need to add a class name for each of those input elements.

**simpler version**
Or if you want to copy all input elements value to #data3 tables corresponding input elements, use this:

```
$( '#data' ).on( 'keyup', 'input, textarea', function() {
    $( '#data3' ).find( '#' + this.id ).val( this.value );
});
```

**Notes**
You can only attach events to an element that already exists in DOM, so you can't directly attach the event to input or textarea element. Instead you can attach the event to `#data` that, I assume, will already be in DOM.

**Without duplicated IDs (ids removed from #data3 table's input elements)**

```
$( '#data' ).on( 'keyup', 'input, textarea', function() {
    $( '#data3' ).find( '[name="' + this.id + '"]' ).val( this.value );
});
```

Comment: thnk u sir but jus for an example since i am newbie i dnt hav much knowledge cn u please do it in one textbox code please that wud be a huge favor fr my project

Comment: I think the last code example should work. Just remove your Javascript onkeyup code from every input element, and add that last code example to your document.ready handler

Comment: @suhail In order to help you more, you should post some HTML code as well, so those `keyup` events makes sense to me.

Comment: @suhail It should. But i strongly recommend to remove `id` attribute from #data3 table input elements since they are not needed, and makes things complicated. The name attributes should be there, however, to find the corresponding element.

Comment: @suhail Updated the code. So remove every `keyup="...` from your `strToAdd` and also remove the `id` attributes from `#data3` table. Only add that little piece of code after your `#addnew` event.

Comment: @suhail Does it throw an error or how it isn't working? Create an JS Fiddle and give me the link so I can help you further.

Comment: sir is der a way to call function inside the textbox while i append it like onkeyup="function()"??

Comment: @suhail Here is the working demo, used as in my answer, http://jsfiddle.net/7jrs3/

Comment: thnks alot sir really u made a huge favor sir thnks for ur help and sorry for irritating u

Comment: @suhail No problem, here's updated code, http://jsfiddle.net/7jrs3/1/ Btw, you probably have a typo, your `srno` and `descrip` input names weren't the same in #data and #data3... fixed that in my JS Fiddle code

Comment: sir how can i applu this function to my every textbox??

Comment: @suhail What do you mean by `textbox`? A `input` or `textarea`? Are those 'textboxes' inside `#data` or in a different container?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.each($('textarea'),function(){
     $(this).on('keyup',function(){
        $('body').append('<textarea>'+$(this).val()+'</textarea>'); 
          });
        });
```

you can check the [jQuery $.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop this code over all your elements

Comment: sir my need is that wen i click the add the two rows should get generated in two different tables and i want that if a user inputs a vales inside a generated textbox the value should get copied to the other textbox which is generated at the same time anyways thnks fr ur anser

Comment: well mine it's an example for textbox values you need $('textarea').val(); @suhail

Comment: but is there a way where i can add this function into my textbox like one i have in javascript like thisonkeyup="document.getElementById("srno_' + currentItem + '").value = this.value;"

Comment: do you need click or keyup? @suhail **onclick=""** exists **onkeyup=""** doesn't exists

Comment: keyup is my need sir onkeyup="document.getElementById("srno_' + currentItem + '").value = this.value;"<-- i am using this code butits not working either but it works fine in other cases

Comment: you tagged as jquery ok check my last update that works for sure

Comment: sir thnks fr ur answer but if u see my code then i my need is for every textbox

Comment: @suhail i can't write all your code, if you need this for each element you have just to adapt my code, using **for(){}** or **$.each()**

Comment: @suhail i updated my code but i think you will not get the logic if you do not document on jquery each() :P